# Recursive multiply function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an assignment where it asks to produce a function that multiplies a positive integer by 123 without using loops or `*` or the divide operator.

```
function multiply(x, y){
    if (y === 0) return 0;
    return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
}
```

I have a function that can multiply 2 numbers but how can I structure this to multiply by a fixed number?

Comment: Is this one of those exercises for how not to write the code? Because use of recursion for this is exactly what you would want to avoid in the real world.

Comment: @vitaly-t it's likely an introduction to recursion - sure, it's not a good task for recursion, but it's clear and well defined. It's easy to see what is happening and why.

Comment: It's just a challenge to see how creative we can be I guess, this is definitely not something to be used in production.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  You want a function where you don't pass it a `y` but instead use a hard-coded value?  Why not just call this function with a hard-coded value?  Also, I think your function is missing an exit condition.  There should probably be an `if (y === 1)` condition as well, no?

Comment: are you allowed to use bitwise and logical operators?

Answer (score 2):

```
function multiply_123(x) {
     return multiply(x, 123);
}
```

or a little better

```
function multiply_123(x) {
     if(x==0) {
         return 0;
     } else {
         if(x > 123) {
             return multiply(x, 123);
     } else {
         return multiply(123, x);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the value if the other value is odd, then add the result of the double of the first value and the half of the other value, better nown as [Ancient Egyptian multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication).

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
    if (b === 1) return a;
    return (b & 1 && a) + multiply(a << 1, b >> 1);
}

console.log(multiply(4, 5));
console.log(multiply(5, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a function that multiplies two numbers together, now you want to have a function that only takes one argument then "sets" the other. This is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)

This is the basic way to do it - make a new function that only takes a single parameter and calls the other function with that, as well as a constant:

```js
function multiply(x, y){
    if (y === 0) return 0;
    return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
}

function multiplyBy123(x) {
  return multiply(x, 123);
}

console.log(multiplyBy123(3));
console.log(multiplyBy123(10));
```

This can be made more generic, too:

```js
function multiply(x, y){
    if (y === 0) return 0;
    return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
}

function multiplyBy(x) {
  return function (y) {
    return multiply(x, y);
  }
}

var multiplyBy123 = multiplyBy(123);

console.log(multiplyBy123(3));
console.log(multiplyBy123(10));
```

This technique is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) - the basics is that you can break up a function with multiple parameters into something that takes one and returns a function that expects the rest. So in this case, `multiplyBy` takes `x` and returns a function that expects `y` then when that function is invoked with the parameter, it calls `multiply` with both `x` and `y`.

An even simpler and generic way to partially apply a function is to use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) which allows you to set some of the parameters. You can set the first one and you will get a function that expects the second parameter:

```js
function multiply(x, y){
    if (y === 0) return 0;
    return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
}

var multiplyBy123 = multiply.bind(null, 123);

console.log(multiplyBy123(3));
console.log(multiplyBy123(10));
```

If you are allowed to change `multiply`, then you can make it even simpler and just use a [default parameter value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) to set `y` to `123` if not specified:

```js
function multiply(x, y = 123){
    if (y === 0) return 0;
    return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
}

console.log(multiply(3));
console.log(multiply(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with tail recursion:

```
const mult = (...args) => {
  const [ a, b, ...rest] = args
  if (args.length === 2) {
    return a * b
  }
  return mult(a * b, ...rest)
}
```